# Card content failed to create component

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to get a minimal **SAP UI Integration Card** of type `Component` setup in Plnkr (to illustrate an issue), but I'm not able to load the card:

```
Unable to load data
Card content failed to create component
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/xK8FQdx2QBZpn4wE

What's missing or incorrectly setup here?

Perhaps a resource roots declaration is missing, but I can't figure out if and how I would need to set this for a UI Integration Card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Component file is being searched at /Component.js, which in this case is `https://run.plnkr.co/Component.js`, but it should be `https://run.plnkr.co/preview/xK8FQdx2QBZpn4wE/Component.js`.
A simple solution to avoid the absolute path problem would be to put all the card code in its own folder https://plnkr.co/edit/GARaxLwFYbUIAkSe

```
project
    card
        manifest.json
        Component.js
        ...
    index.html
```